# How to perform the same function in several checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="" id="1" onclick="enableNextButton('5')">
<input type="checkbox" name="2" value="" id="2" onclick="enableNextButton('5')">
<input type="checkbox" name="3" value="" id="3" onclick="enableNextButton('5')">

<button type="button" id="next-btn-5" disabled>Submit</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function enableNextButton(quizID) {
    if($("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked') == true){
        $('#next-btn-'+quizID).prop('disabled', false);
    }else{
        $('#next-btn-'+quizID).prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it is only working for the first checkbox, for others it does not work, it does not fulfill the function.

Comment: In jQuery you need an `.each` loop. If you're a newbie, which seems like the case, I would avoid using jQuery altogether since you can easily animate with CSS and `.querySelectorAll` exists. You would still need a loop, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery it is simpler to create  a jQuery event listener than use an inline `onclick` and use a data attribute for the nextId value

```js
$(':checkbox[data-next]').change(function(){
   $('#next-btn-' + $(this).data('next')).prop('disabled', !this.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>5:<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="" id="1" data-next="5"/></label>
<label>6:<input type="checkbox" name="2" value="" id="2"  data-next="6"/></label>
<label>7:<input type="checkbox" name="3" value="" id="3"  data-next="7"/></label>
<br/><br/>
<button type="button" id="next-btn-5" disabled>Button 5</button>
<button type="button" id="next-btn-6" disabled>Button 6</button>
<button type="button" id="next-btn-7" disabled>Button 7</button>
```

Comment: Great! it's possible to do this for textarea input? When typing releases, deleting all text blocks...

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking to do with textarea. Probably better to open another question and explain it in detail

Comment: Same thing with the checkbox, the difference is that it should remove the disable from the button when the user types text, and should add the disable if the user deletes all the text, that is, if there is nothing typed.

Comment: Just check length of value when textarea changes

Comment: I'm really new to this area, but is it something like that? `$(this).val().length;`  I would love if you could provide me with an example.

Comment: Yes that would tell you if the textarea had any content

Comment: one last question, is there any way to issue an alert when someone clicks the button while it is disabled? Only while it is disabled..

Comment: There are no events registered on a disabled element

Comment: Hmm.. So there is no way to issue an `alert` when someone clicks the button while disabled?

Comment: How could you if events don't register? Don't disable it if you need events

Answer (score 1):

I would use the data-* attribute to store the button selector (ID in your case):

```js
$("[data-enable]").on("input", function() {
  const selector = this.dataset.enable
  const $group = $(`[data-enable="${selector}"]`);
  let ok = false;
  if (/checkbox|radio/.test(this.type)) ok = $group.filter(":checked").length > 0;
  if (/textarea/.test(this.type)) ok = $(this).val().trim().length > 0;
  $(selector).attr("disabled", !ok);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="5-1" value="1" data-enable="#next-btn-5">
<input type="checkbox" name="5-2" value="2" data-enable="#next-btn-5">
<input type="checkbox" name="5-3" value="3" data-enable="#next-btn-5">
<button type="button" id="next-btn-5" disabled>Submit 5</button>

<br>

<input type="radio" name="30" value="1" data-enable="#next-btn-30">
<input type="radio" name="30" value="2" data-enable="#next-btn-30">
<input type="radio" name="30" value="3" data-enable="#next-btn-30">
<button type="button" id="next-btn-30" disabled>Submit 30</button>

<br>

<textarea name="foo" data-enable="#next-btn-31"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="next-btn-31" disabled>Submit 31</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect, it's possible to do this for textarea input? When typing releases, deleting all text blocks.

Comment: @zecaluis If this answer your original question, please accept it. If you have further doubts about different subjects you can ask again in a different questions.

Comment: Can you put an example in your answer with `textarea`? I noticed that you exemplified it with `checkbox` and `radio`.

Comment: @zecaluis does this helps?

Comment: Oww! Excellent, one last question, is there any way to issue an alert when someone clicks the button while it is disabled? Only while it is disabled.